# How do you set a rule to move sent items in Mail?

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

I've got a rule set in my Apple Mail app to move email older than 90 days out of my inbox to a separate local mailbox (to free up some space on my server – I use imap).

My inbox rule is

```
If [all] of the following conditions are met:

Account [My Main Account]

Date Received / Is Greater Than / 90 days

Perform the following action

Move Message to mailbox: [My Local Backup Mailbox]
```

That works well, but I want to do the same for sent items.

I can't see any rule options that affect the Sent items folder (or any other specific mailbox for that matter)

Any idea?

I'm on El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Just change "Date Received" by "Date Sent".

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this could be of any help?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion – not sure why it's been downvoted (i've upvoted it to counteract). The *Date sent* field is a bit ambiguous I think.. is it date sent by any sender (in that case it will go through the inbox) or is it Date sent by the account, in that case it would be the sent items..

Comment: Thank you, very kind of you. Just went through my old notes (remembering that I had the same need once - to sort _outgoing_ messages) and realised that Apple still didn't address it. Mail cannot process outgoing messages :( The only solution I had for that time was paid add-on called 'Mail Act-On'. You can read more about it [here](https://smallcubed.com/mao/).

Comment: Ugh.. paid add-on, bummer :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the condition that the sender's email address is your own? The rule has to meet ‘all’ conditions. For Example:

```
If ‘all’ the following conditions are met:
‘Date sent’ ‘is greater than’ ‘90’ days old
‘+’
‘From’ ‘contains’ ‘(insert your own email address)’
Perform the following actions:
‘Move message’ to mailbox: ‘(specify the destination folder)’
```

NB Caveat, this is an untested suggestion!
I have not yet tried this myself, but I am facing the issue as I have limited IMAP server storage space but need to retain sent emails and I may experiment with the above.